# Ubuntu 16.04 openstack installation: charms messages

Tags: juju, openstack, conjure-up

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a `vmware esxi 6` vm and it is working fine.
I followed instructions on how to install `conjure-up` and `openstack` as given on http://conjure-up.io/ . After a long time of `juju` bootstrapping, I see this message regarding charms as depicted in the attached screenshot:

[image: openstack message screenshot]

I am new to Ubuntu and `openstack` and would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

This screen gives you an overview of what services will be deployed. This is changing in the next release of conjure-up to be more tutorial like and less overwhelming. For now just tabbing over to commit will accept all the defaults and give you a fully deployed OpenStack.